# How to redirect all incoming messages to a Gmail email address using Microsoft Outlook 2013?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2013

I use Microsoft Outlook 2013 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

How to redirect all emails I receive on Outlook to a Gmail email address?

Answer (score 1):

You can auto forward emails in outlook 2013 by setting up a rule under tools>rules and alerts

Here's a guide with the specifics
https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Automatically-forward-my-messages-to-another-e-mail-account-9f124e4a-749e-4288-a266-2d009686b403#bm2

Answer (score 1):

Add a rule:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Add this rule as well the same way:

[image]

These two added rules should cover all cases, i.e. all emails will be automatically forwarded to your Gmail account.